# How many linear extension has a partial ordering relation

Tags: order-theory

i need some clarification about linear ordering:
Let R a partial ordering relation :
R=( { (1,2),(1,4),(2,7)(3,4),(3,5),(4,6)(5,6)(6,8),(7,8)}, =< )

How many linear extension has R ?

I went to the definition of a linear extension: i saw that a linear extension of a partial ordered set is an extension which is a linear order, so here is what i found :

R* =({(1,2),(1,3)(1,4),(1,5),(1,6),(1,7),(1,8),(2,3),(2,4),(2,5),(2,6),(2,7),(2,8),(3,4),(3,5),(3,6),(3,7),(3,8),(4,5),(4,6),(4,7),(4,8),(5,6),(5,7),(5,8),(6,7),(6,8),(7,8) } =<)

So we have 20 linear extension of R ? is it how we find linear extension of a relation?

Is there a general formula ?

Thanks for help

Comment: Your $R^*$ is ***one*** linear extension of $R.$ How do you get from that that there are $20$ linear extensions of $R?$ What are the other $19?$

Comment: By the way, $R$ isn't exactly a "partial ordering relation" according to the usual definition, because it's not transitive: for example, $(1,2)\in R$ and $(2,7)\in R,$ but $(1,7)\notin R.$ The **transitive closure** of $R$ is a partial ordering relation.